# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ $G_{\delta}$ or $F_{\sigma}$?

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that $\mathbb{Z}$  is $G_{\delta}$ or $F_{\sigma}$.

Denote : $D = \mathbb{Z}$
Let's suppose that D  is $G_{\delta}$ . $$ D  \textit{ is }G_{\delta}\Rightarrow \exists \{V_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}  \} \in \tau$$. $$D = \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}}( \bigcup \limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(n - \frac{1}{2^{k}},n+ \frac{1}{2^{k}})) \Rightarrow G \textit{ is not }G_{\delta}$$

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your definition for $G_{\delta}$ is not very clear. Isn’t a $G_{\delta}$ set one which can be written as a countable intersection of open sets?

Comment: Yes, this is another definition I found in a book. How to write it more accurately?

Comment: Notice the use of "or" need not be exclusive in this context.
Also I think the symbolic definition that you are looking for is:

$D  \textit{ is }G_{\delta} \iff \exists \{V_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}  \} \in \tau : D=\bigcap\limits_{n =1}^\infty V_n$.

Comment: Technically, it should actually read $\exists \{V_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}  \} \subset \tau$.  Because $\{V_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}  \}$ is a collection of subsets, not a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set $G_n:= \bigcup \limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left(k - \frac{1}{n},k+ \frac{1}{n}\right)$ is open in the topology induced by the Euclidean Metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (any union of open sets is open). So the set $\bigcap\limits_{n =1}^\infty G_n$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set by definition. Since $\mathbb{Z} \subset G_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{n =1}^\infty G_n$. Suppose $p \in \bigcap\limits_{n =1}^\infty G_n$. So for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have that $|p-k|<\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we see that $p=k$. Therefore $\mathbb{Z} =\bigcap\limits_{n =1}^\infty G_n$.

Notice that a singleton is closed in the topology induced by the Euclidean Metric on $\mathbb{R}$. IE; if $p \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\{p\}=\mathbb{R} \setminus \left((-\infty, p) \bigcup \, (p, \infty) \right)$. So $\mathbb{Z}=\bigcup \limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{k\}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set, since it is the countable union of closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the countable union of (closed) singleton sets, so it is $F_{\sigma}$.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is an open subset of itself, so we have $\mathbb{Z} = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}$ is also a $G_{\delta}$ set.